# Creating a graph of nodes and edges from image matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, graph

I have a binary matrix that contains the pixel information of a skeleton.I
wish to create a graph with nodes and edges out of this binary matrix.

Using options like `graph = MorphologicalGraph[skeleton]` in Mathematica, converts
multiple edges that lie between two nodes to a single edge.Since I don't
want to miss the details of multiple edges in the graph, the skeleton image has been converted into an image matrix.

Here is a python code using which the binary matrix (file.mat) is loaded in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import scipy.io as spio
mat = spio.loadmat('file.mat', squeeze_me=True)
print(type(mat))
print(type(mat.get('Expression1')))
imshow(mat.get('Expression1'), interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Here is an input file[file.mat](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/cytoscape/blob/master/file.mat)

I would like to know if there is a way to process the binary matrix containing the pixel information and create a graph.